# Do I need visa if I am moving from India to Ireland and I have connecting flight via Zurich (connection time 3Hr05Min)?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, zurich

I am traveling to Dublin from Mumbai by Swiss Airways via Zurich with a stopover of 3hr 05 min.

Will I need a transit visa (or any other visa) for the Zurich stopover?

Comment: No.............

Answer (score 2):

I assume your nationality is Indian and you hold such a passport. Since you need a visa for Ireland (or a UK visa for the Irish Visa Waiver Programme), you don't need to worry about a transit visa in the Schengen Area. This is because you will already be holding a visa from an EU state.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. You [don't need](https://www.sem.admin.ch/content/dam/data/sem/rechtsgrundlagen/weisungen/visa/bfm/bfm-anh01-liste2-e.pdf) a Swiss Transit Visa